# TypeError when trying to call National Rail SOAP API via Node

Tags: xml, node.js, soap, typeerror, node-soap

I'm trying to access the National Rail API using [node-soap](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap%20%22node-soap).

Documentation is here: https://lite.realtime.nationalrail.co.uk/OpenLDBWS/

I am new to SOAP so this might not be an issue with the API. I am getting a TypeError with whatever I attempt...

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'Body' of undefined

Here is the code I am using to try and make a call:

```
var soap = require('soap');
var url = 'https://lite.realtime.nationalrail.co.uk/OpenLDBWS/wsdl.aspx?ver=2014-02-20';
var soapHeader = '<com:AccessToken>MY_TOKEN</com:AccessToken>';

soap.createClient(url, function(err, client){

  var args = {
    numRows : 10,
    crs : 'LAN'
  };

  client.addSoapHeader(soapHeader);

  client.GetDepartureBoard(args, function(err, result){
    if(err){
      console.log('error!');
      throw err;
    }
    console.log(result);
  });  
});
```

Using node-soap I can also get the request envelope, this is the contents:

```
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tns="http://thalesgroup.com/RTTI/2014-02-20/ldb/"
    xmlns:tok="http://thalesgroup.com/RTTI/2013-11-28/Token/types"
    xmlns:ct="http://thalesgroup.com/RTTI/2007-10-10/ldb/commontypes"
    xmlns:ldbt="http://thalesgroup.com/RTTI/2012-01-13/ldb/types"
    xmlns:ldbt2="http://thalesgroup.com/RTTI/2014-02-20/ldb/types">
    <soap:Header>
        <com:AccessToken>MY_TOKEN</com:AccessToken>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <tns:GetDepartureBoardRequest
            xmlns:tns="http://thalesgroup.com/RTTI/2014-02-20/ldb/"
            xmlns="http://thalesgroup.com/RTTI/2014-02-20/ldb/">
            <tns:numRows>10</tns:numRows>
            <tns:crs>LAN</tns:crs>
        </tns:GetDepartureBoardRequest>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your soap header was formatted incorrectly, it needs '<'AccessToken'>''<'/AccessToken'>' 
wrapped around it

```
var args, soap, soapHeader, url;

soap = require('soap');

url = 'https://lite.realtime.nationalrail.co.uk/OpenLDBWS/wsdl.aspx?ver=2014-02-20';

soapHeader = '<AccessToken><TokenValue>Your access token</TokenValue></AccessToken>'

// or you can write it as an object
//soapHeader = {
//    AccessToken: {
//        TokenValue: "Your access token"
//    }
//};

args = {
    numRows: 10,
    crs: 'BSK'
};

soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
    client.addSoapHeader(soapHeader);
    return client.GetArrivalDepartureBoard(args, function(err, result) {
        return console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    });
});
```